# Determine orientation of spherical polygon without trig functions

Tags: numerical-methods, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Is there a way of testing the orientation of a spherical polygon given an *ordered* list of its vertices that doesn’t involve computing (inverse) trigonometric functions? The polygon is not necessarily convex but it partitions the sphere in a way that both the north and south poles are on the same side of the boundary. The interior of the polygon (so that we have a fixed clockwise and counterclockwise direction) is the region that contains neither pole.

Comment: How are defined the vertices? Cartesian coordinates? Other?

Comment: "both the north and south poles are on the same side of the boundary": I doubt that this information has any relevance. The orientation does not depend on the position of the poles.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net does it matter?

Comment: If you want to (try to) avoid trigonometric computation, It can be interesting to understand how the inputs are defined.

Comment: @taylorswift: of course. If a method requires Cartesian coordinates and you only have the spherical ones, you are stuck.

Comment: @YvesDaoust they are cartesian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n = (0,0,1)$ and $s = (0,0,-1)$ be the north and south poles.

Since the spherical polygon $P$ doesn't intersect $s$, you can stereographic project $P$ with respect to $s$ and map it to a polygon-like region $P'$ (with curved edges) on the tangent plane $T_n$ of unit sphere at $n$.

$$S^3 \setminus \{ s \} \supset P \ni (x,y,z) \quad\mapsto\quad
 \left(\frac{2x}{1+z},\frac{2y}{1+z},1\right) \in P' \subset T_n$$

The orientation of $P$ will be the same as its image $P'$. One can determine the
later by looking at the sign of its signed area.

Let's say the vertices of $P$ are 
$p_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for $0 \le i < m$ and let $p_m = p_0$.
When the vertices are find enough and $P'$ can be approximated by an
ordinary polygon with straight edges, we have

$$\begin{align}\verb/Orientation/(P) 
& = \verb/Orientaion/(P') = \verb/sign/(\verb/signed-area/(P'))\\
& = \verb/sign/\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i}{(1+z_i)(1+z_{i+1})} \right)
\end{align}
$$
This approximation can fail in two cases, either some of the edges in $P$ is very long or very close to south pole $s$. In both cases, subdivide corresponding edges in a fine enough manner will solve the problem.

Comment: how fine do the subdivisions have to be?

Comment: @taylorswift it depends. the problem typically occurs when you have vertices $p_{i-1}$, $p_i$, $p_{i+1}$ where $|p_{i-1} - p_{i+1}| \ll |p_{i-1} - p_i|, |p_{i+1} - p_i|$. In that case, I will subdivide the edges $p_{i-1}p_i$ and $p_ip_{i+1}$ to make the sub-edges have same order of length with $p_{i-1}p_{i+1}$.

Comment: and these are distances measured in rectangular space right? and what about the close to south pole case?

Comment: @taylorswift for those close to south pole, I will subdivide the sides so that their lengths has order 1. It really depends on how the polygons are generated and going to be used. For typical CG application where the polygons looks like a circular patch, there is no need of all these subdivision. When the polygon is sufficiently pathological, it will be better to switch back to the original calculation with trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

Project the vertices on a unit cube centered on the sphere to get a polyhedron. This takes Euclidean norms of vectors, but no trigonometry.

Then you compute the signed volume by the shoelace formula generalized to 3D.

Comment: what if the polygon is spread across multiple faces of the cube?

Comment: @taylorswift: you "wrap" the polygon onto the faces.

Comment: but the projection will not be planar… the projection could very well touch all 6 sides of the cube

Comment: @taylorswift: that's what I mean.

Comment: all I could find on "3D shoelace formula" was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710682/algorithm-for-partially-filling-a-polygonal-mesh/14713130#14713130) but that requires finding a triangulation for the polyhedron. and remember it wouldn’t be a perfect cube; an edge that crosses a cube edge would create a bevel, it wouldn’t fill out the available volume of the cube (if that makes sense).
maybe a worked example would help more

Comment: @taylorswift: you can decompose the volume in vertical prisms, making sure to keep the sign (this is a generalization of the 2D principle). A crossing edge must indeed be "broken". Consider the intersection of the plane formed by the origin and the edge, with the cube.

Comment: @taylorswift: I didn't say that the approach would be easy.

Comment: what do you mean by decompose the volume in vertical prisms?

Comment: @taylorswift: like you decompose a polygon in trapezoids